# How can i move my UIImage vertically from top to bottom

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

i want the UIImage to move on the screen vertically downwards and when it reaches to the end it should again start from the top. how can i do it???

please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your UIImage is in a UIImageView and the image view is 320 x 480 in size...

Your animation block can call a method when it is complete.  This method resets the position of your UIImageView and then starts the animation over.

Animation Block:

```
-(void)animate {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myCallback:finished:context:)];

    CGRect frame = yourImageView.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 480);
    yourImageView.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Callback:

```
(void)myCallback:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

    CGRect frame = yourImageView.frame;
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    yourImageView.frame = frame;
    [self animate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i wrote my code
moving.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface movingViewController : UIViewController{ 
UIImageView *imageView1;
}
@property (retain , nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView1;
@end
```

moving.m

```
#import "movingViewController.h"
@synthesize imageView1;
-(void) animate {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(myCallback:finished:context:)];

CGRect frame = imageView1.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 480)
imageView1.frame = frame;

[UIView commitAnimations];  
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
 }


 -(void)myCallback:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

CGRect frame = imageView1.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0)
imageView1.frame = frame;
[self animate];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}
- (void)viewDidUnload {}
- (void)dealloc {
    [imageView1 dealloc];
    [imageView1 release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Im sorry to ask simple questions but im very new to Xcode

is that the correct way

Comment: I have fixed the errors but when i Try to build and run the code, im getting a blank screen.. why is that happening for?